# Is it possible to start background workers sequentially?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, sequential

I want to use 3 background workers in sequential order.

First one should do a job, update UI and start the second background worker which does the same and then starts the last one. This should repeat only when a button is clicked again. Is such behavior possible to obtain?

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     Bw1= = new BackgroundWorker();
     Bw2= = new BackgroundWorker();
     Bw3= = new BackgroundWorker();
     Bw1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Bw1_DoWork);
     Bw1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler
                    (Bw1_ProgressChanged);
     Bw1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler
                    (Bw1_RunWorkerCompleted);
     Bw1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
     Bw1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            ...
     Bw3.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Bw3_DoWork);
     Bw3.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler
                    (Bw3_ProgressChanged);
     Bw3.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler
                    (Bw3_RunWorkerCompleted);
     Bw3.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
     Bw3.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

}

private void btnStartAsyncOperation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     btnStartAsyncOperation.Enabled = false;
     btnCancel.Enabled = true;
     // Kickoff the worker thread to begin its DoWork function.
     BW1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

//THE DO WORK PART
//UPDATE UI
//tHEN

void BW1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    STOP BW1;
    BW2.RUN();
}
        ...
    //Until BW 3 completes and here this should stop until next click
```

Comment: Start `Bw2` after `Bw1` completes, and `Bw3` after `Bw2` completes. Or use [async/await](http://msdn.com/async).

Comment: Why not have one background worker that performs all three tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the background worker is not clear.

However, you could do the following (assuming there is no legitimate `async` *IO work*, and these *tasks* don't need to be run from a non *threadpool thread* ).

<sub>***Note** : If there was legitimate `async` IO work, you wouldn't need to wrap/offload to a `Task` and would just use `await`)*</sub>

The advantages are :

- It's sequential
- It factors simpler (less degrees of freedom)
- It's easier to read
- It uses the *Async Await Pattern* (and frees up the *message pump*/*UI thread*)
- And will work well with *UI updates*

**Example**

```
private async void btnStartAsyncOperation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   try
   {

      await Task.Run(() => FirstTask1());

      // update the ui

      await Task.Run(() => FirstTask2());

      // update the ui

      await Task.Run(() => FirstTask3());

      // update the ui

   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
       // make sure you catch or do something with exception
   }
}
```

<sub>***Note** : Because this is an `event` and `async void` is appropriate, you need to make sure you deal with your exceptions (as this is unobserved). You might also want to guard against double clicks.*</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your explicit answer. It helped me a lot to understand what i was doing wrong in my project and how i should have structured my app from the beginning. I will follow this pattern and refactor what I've done.